Pytorch Error when fine-tuning "google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k" on video datasets with the Huggingface Trainer API
I am trying to read custom video datasets with their labels in a csv file and transfer train them using Huggingface Trainer with google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k model.
Here is what I have implemented so far but encountered a Key 42 error code.
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.io.video as video
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from transformers import ViTFeatureExtractor, ViTForImageClassification, TrainingArguments, Trainer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
import glob
import av
from tqdm import tqdm

# Define classes
classes = ['class_0', 'class_1']

# Define a custom dataset for video frames
class VideoDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, video_paths, labels, transform=None):
        self.video_paths = video_paths
        self.labels = labels
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.video_paths)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        frames, _, _ = video.read_video(self.video_paths[idx], pts_unit='sec')
        sample = {'frames': frames, 'label': self.labels[idx]}

        if self.transform:
            sample['frames'] = [self.transform(frame) for frame in sample['frames']]

        return sample

# Define transformations for preprocessing frames
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
])

# Function to preprocess each frame
def preprocess_frame(frame):
    frame = transforms.ToPILImage()(frame)
    frame = transform(frame)
    return frame

# Function to preprocess the dataset
def preprocess_dataset(dataset):
    return dataset

# Define training arguments
training_args = TrainingArguments(
    output_dir="./trained",
    per_device_train_batch_size=4,
    num_train_epochs=3,
    logging_dir='./logs',
    logging_steps=100,
)

# Load the ViT model and feature extractor
model = ViTForImageClassification.from_pretrained("google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k")
feature_extractor = ViTFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained("google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k")

#Load training Videos
train_videos =  glob.glob("./dataset100/train/all/*.mp4")

#Load Labels
train_df = pd.read_csv('./train100.csv',names=header_list)
labels = train_df['tag']

#Split dataset into train and validation sets
train_paths, val_paths,train_labels, val_labels= train_test_split(train_videos, labels, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

# Create datasets and preprocess them
train_dataset = VideoDataset(train_paths, train_labels, transform=transform)
val_dataset = VideoDataset(val_paths, val_labels, transform=transform)
train_dataset = preprocess_dataset(train_dataset)
val_dataset = preprocess_dataset(val_dataset)

print("Number of training videos:", len(train_paths))
print("Number of validation videos:", len(val_paths))
print("Number of training labels:", len(train_labels))
print("Number of validation labels:", len(val_labels))

print("Training videos:", train_videos[:5])
print("Training labels:", train_labels[:5])

# Define function to compute accuracy
def compute_accuracy(pred):
    labels = pred.label_ids
    preds = pred.predictions.argmax(-1)
    return {"accuracy": (preds == labels).mean()}

# Define Trainer
trainer = Trainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset,
    compute_metrics=compute_accuracy,`your text`
)

# Train the model
trainer.train()

Here is the error message I received and I would really appreciate some help.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File c:\Users\Code\venv\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3791, in Index.get_loc(self, key)
   3790 try:
-> 3791     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3792 except KeyError as err:

File index.pyx:152, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File index.pyx:181, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2606, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2630, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 42

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[31], line 121
    112 trainer = Trainer(
    113     model=model,
    114     args=training_args,
   (...)
...
   3801     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3802     #  the TypeError.
   3803     self._check_indexing_error(key)

KeyError: 42

